# How are recursive lists implementated internally?

Tags: python, list, recursion, implementation

In python, a list can contain itself.

```
a_list = []
a_list.append(a_list)
```

When printed, it displays `[...]` for that item. I.E., this:

```
a_list = [1, 2, 3]
a_list.append(a_list)
```

would print `[1, 2, 3, [...]]`. Now, in CPython, how does this work?
Does that element of the list contain the ID of the value? Or the memory location? Is their just some sort of special placeholder marker that, when referenced, will replace itself with the original list?

Comment: @miradulo That technically doesn't describe the implementation, just what it _is_. Now, there's a comment that contains the implementation, but answers are generally easier to search for, so it would be best to have a separate question for exactly that

Comment: @miradulo Wait... why did you mark this question as a duplicate of a duplicate? That seems rather inefficient

Comment: PascalCase: Python is open-source. Suggest you read the source code for these sorts of questions (because it's the definitive source).

Comment: @miradulo Yes, that is in fact the case. Hence, the [implementation] tag

Comment: @PascalCase I added a third question that has an answer addressing the internals - it also has over 1000 views. Does that address your question?

Comment: I would say the answer is really just a link to the relevant source code. I understand not wanting to hunt down the answer in the code, but if you're not willing to read it, get out. https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/03c65fc349c0/Objects/listobject.c#l361

Comment: In CPython lists are backed by a primitive array of Py_Object oiinters

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga *Py_Object pointers?